# deno connect to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, deno

I've tried to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VF38U2qd27Q, but to no avail.
I realised that the syntax in the video already obsolete for example connectWithUri to become connect.

but when I tried to connect to mongo using [deno_mongo](https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.20.1) with the latest docs, it still not working.

```
import { MongoClient } from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.20.1/mod.ts";

const dbString = `mongodb://${mongoUser}:${mongoPass}@${mongoHost}:${mongoPort}`;
const client = new MongoClient();
client.connect(dbString);
const db = client.database(mongoDB)
this.users = db.collection<UserSchema>("users");
```

Then I found another library [denodb](https://deno.land/x/denodb@v1.0.18) but again can't connect to mongodb:

```
import { Database } from 'https://deno.land/x/denodb/mod.ts';

const dbString = `mongodb://${mongoUser}:${mongoPass}@${mongoHost}:${mongoPort}`;
this.db = new Database('mongo', {
  uri: dbString,
  database: mongoDB
});
```

the error message:

```
error: Uncaught AssertionError
deno        |     throw new AssertionError(msg);
deno        |           ^
deno        |     at assert (asserts.ts:152:11)
deno        |     at MongoClient.database (client.ts:48:5)
deno        |     at new connectDB (connectDB.ts:35:23)
```

which part is wrong?

Comment: *not working* - this is not a really helpful description of the problem. Usually there's a reason for something *not working* and you get error codes or exceptions for it.  Can you please provide more information? Btw. it's just Deno, not Denojs.

Comment: because the error message also confusing, but I will provide the error info in the thread

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the deno_mongo README on [GitHub](https://github.com/denodrivers/deno_mongo).

For a local database you should use

```js
//Connecting to a Local Database
await client.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

And if you are connecting to Mongo Atlas Database (and probably any other remote database) you should use:

```js
//Connecting to a Mongo Atlas Database
await client.connect({
  db: "<db_name>",
  tls: true,
  servers: [
    {
      host: "<db_cluster_url>",
      port: 27017,
    },
  ],
  credential: {
    username: "<username>",
    password: "<password>",
    db: "<db_name>",
    mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-1",
  },
});
```

**FYI**

If you are using Mongo Atlas make sure to split up the connection string you get from 'Connection Wizard' in the Mongo Atlas dashboard over 3 (or how many replicas you have) entries in the server array. Like this:

```
servers: [
  {
    host: this.dbUrl1, // e.g. <name-of-cluster>-00-00.fbnrc.mongodb.net
    port: 27017,
  },
  {
    host: this.dbUrl2, // e.g. <name-of-cluster>-00-01.fbnrc.mongodb.net
    port: 27017,
  },
  {
    host: this.dbUrl3, // e.g. <name-of-cluster>-00-02.fbnrc.mongodb.net
    port: 27017,
  }
]
```

You get the connection string by:

- Click 'Clusters' under Data storage (left side of the screen)
- Click 'Connect' button
- Click 'Connect to Application'
- Select Driver: 'Node.js' and Version: '2.2.12 or later'

Connection string is displayed below. The servers are listed in a comma separated manner like this:

`...<name-of-cluster>-00-00.fbnrc.mongodb.net:27017,<name-of-cluster>-00-01.fbnrc.mongodb.net:27017,<name-of-cluster>-00-02.fbnrc.mongodb.net:27017...`

**FYI-2**

Make sure the master replica is listed first in the server array. Because if you want to do insertions into the database the master replica should be targeted. For me this was the 2nd mongo url, therefore the following server array worked for me:

```
servers: [
  {
    host: this.dbUrl2,
    port: 27017,
  },
  {
    host: this.dbUrl1,
    port: 27017,
  },
  {
    host: this.dbUrl3,
    port: 27017,
  }
]
```

Comment: Could not get this to work before seeing this post. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

the below code is working for me.

```
import { DataTypes, Database, Model } from 'https://deno.land/x/denodb/mod.ts';

const db = new Database('mongo', {
  host: 'mongodb://localhost:27017',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  database: 'DBMYAPP',
});
console.log(db)
```

Comment: that means no authentication to the database? u didn't use user and password for the database? is it safe? is it the best practice?

Comment: No it is not a best practice. This is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue while updating deno_mongo to the latest version. Use `await` to resolve `client.connect` method

**Try this:**

```
import { MongoClient } from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.20.1/mod.ts";

const dbString = `mongodb://${mongoUser}:${mongoPass}@${mongoHost}:${mongoPort}`;
const client = new MongoClient();
await client.connect(dbString);
const db = client.database(mongoDB)
this.users = db.collection<UserSchema>("users");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but actually I still can't connect my deno to mongo bcs of the auth issue. The author of deno_mongo has create the issue https://github.com/manyuanrong/deno_mongo/issues/129#issuecomment-751727134.

Comment: I have not faced this issue as i have local mongodb setup.

Comment: do you use credential on your local mongodb?

Comment: No i dont have. still you getting same error?

Comment: that's why u didnt get the error, my string is like this: `mongodb://${mongoUser}:${mongoPass}@${mongoHost}:${mongoPort}` while yours `mongodb://${mongoHost}:${mongoPort}`, I can't use your string in production, because everyone can access the DB by knowing the server's ip address.

Comment: I wil try with password and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on windows 10, so try this
on your local mongodb:

```
await client.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
```